# How can I draw lines around a circle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

[image: lines around a circle]

how can I draw lines around a circle using HTMLcanvas? I am more interested on the math.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compute the point on the circle and then the point that lies outside of the circle. Then use `beginPath`, `moveTo`, `lineTo` and finally `stroke` to draw the line.

To compute a point at distance `d` from a point of coords `(x, y)` and angle `an` you can use the following formula:

```
(x + Math.cos(an) * d, y + Math.sin(an) * d)
```

Now you compute 2 points, one using `d` as the radius of the circle, and then d as something bigger than radius, depending on your needs.

I'm assuming that the `an` is in radians, if it's measured in degrees then you can convert it like this:

`const rad = an / 180 * Math.PI`

Comment: Code example please?

Answer (score 0):

I've cobbled this quickly together:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//draw a circle
ctx.fillStyle = '#4A8';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 250, 50, 0, 6.282);
ctx.fill();

//draw 12 lines
for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    let a = 360 / 12 * i
  drawLine(a)
}


function drawLine(angle) {
  /*
  parametric form from wikipedia:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations

  x,y are origin, r is radius a is angle
  x = cx + r * cos(a)
  y = cy + r * sin(a)
  */
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  //thanks Radu!
  const rad = angle / 180 * Math.PI

  //250 is the center of the circly both for x & y
  //starting point on the circumfence of the circle
  let x0 = 250 + 50 * Math.cos(rad)
  let y0 = 250 + 50 * Math.sin(rad)
  //endpoint of the stroke further outside with a length of 100
  let x1 = 250 + 100 * Math.cos(rad)
  let y1 = 250 + 100 * Math.sin(rad)
  
  //draw from x0 to x1
  ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
  ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
  ctx.stroke(); 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rokt0v51/

Result:

[image]